# RSpecでFactoryBotを使い、POSTメソッドに関するリクエストSpecを書くのはどうすれば良いか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

## やりたいこと

RailsアプリでRSpecを使ってリクエストテストを行っています。
`User`に関連する子データとして`Post`があり、それぞれFactoryBotを使ってファクトリーを作っていて、リクエストテストで`POSTメソッド`を明示的に使用して新規`Post`レコードを作成したときのレコード数の変化と、リダイレクトされたHTTPステータスのテストを行いたいです。
また、`User`モデルはdeviseで自動生成されたモデルを使っています。

## モデル

###### app/models/user.rb

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :posts
end
```

###### app/models/post.rb

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

## 各モデルのFactoryのソース

###### spec/factories/users.rb

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email { "test@example.com" }
    password { "123456" }
    password_confirmation { "123456" }
    name { "Test" }
  end
end
```

###### spec/factories/posts.rb

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    date { Date.new.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }
    start_time { Time.new.strftime("%H:%M") }
    end_time { Time.new.strftime("%H:%M") }
    kind_of_climbing { 0 }
    sequence(:describe) { |n| "test test#{n}" }
  end
end
```

## Postのリクエストスペック

###### spec/requests/posts_spec.rb

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "/posts", type: :request do
  
  let(:valid_attributes) {
    {
      date: Date.new.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
      start_time: Time.new.strftime("%H:%M"),
      end_time: Time.new.strftime("%H:%M"),
      kind_of_climbing: 0,
      describe: 'test test'
    }
  }

  let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }

  before do
    sign_in user
    @post = FactoryBot.create(:post, user_id: user.id)
  end

  describe "POST /create" do
    context "with valid parameters" do
      it "creates a new Post" do
        expect {
          post posts_url, params: { post: valid_attributes }
        }.to change(Post, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "redirects to the created post" do
        post posts_url, params: { post: valid_attributes }
        expect(response).to redirect_to(post_url(Post.last))
      end
    end
  end

end
```

## 質問内容

上記のリクエストスペックで、最初にletで`user`という変数に入れたオブジェクトに関連する`Post`をPOSTメソッドで作成するようにしたいのですが、どのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

## 試したこと

###### spec/requests/posts_spec.rb

```rb
it "creates a new Post" do
  expect {
    # post posts_url, params: { post: valid_attributes }
    user.posts.create( valid_attributes )
  }.to change(Post, :count).by(1)
end
```

とすることで、`Post`に新規レコードを作成し、カウントを1つ上げるテストをすることはできたのですが、これだとPOSTメソッドのURLに投げていないので、その後のリダイレクトをテストすることができませんでした。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

テストの問題というよりも実装の修正が必要かなと思いました
ログインが必要なアプリケーションであればposts#createでログインユーザーに紐づくpostを作成するように実装されていれば

`post posts_url, params: { post: valid_attributes }`
でログイユーザー（この場合は `user`）に紐づくpostが作成されます

Comment: ありがとうございました！ご回答がヒントになって、テスト側でリダイレクト先を間違っていたのが原因だったことに気づきました。